# css responsive not working and overwriting my inline style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a wordpress site and i am using bootstrap css for a popup. Please check the page here: http://aboutpubliseek.staging.wpengine.com/test-page/

When I reduce the width of the browser less then 770px the text box for email reduces in height. I found no way to solve it. I used inline css for input element, I used media query with !important tag, I also tried with removing all other css but bootstratp.css. But same result. So I think issue with bootstrap.css. Some thing is overwriting my css when I reduce the width less then 770px.

Please check the following code i used for test:

```
@media screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:770px){
    #gform_fields_2 {
        input[type='email'] {
            background-color:#EEE;
            padding:5px 10px !important;
            min-height: 30px !important;
        }
    }
}
```

Here background color works but padding.
Can you please help me to sort out this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
min-height: 42px !important;
```

to this

```
#gform_fields_2 input[type='email'] {

}
```

so it becomes

```
#gform_fields_2 input[type='email'] {
/*..css defs that are already there */
min-height: 42px !important;
}
```

this is in your commander_less.css file

Comment: Thanks for you ans. But I already tried with this style. The height will be 30px actually. But problem is when resize the browser by reducing width with less the 770px then input[type=email] filed is changed in height. Please check yourself.